# SAP CPI - PHP Curl to get Token

Tags: curl, token

I am trying to get a token from SAPI CPI, but am getting a 401 - Bad credentials returned. Here is my code: -

```
$client_id="***";
$client_secret="***";
              
// Define the POST request to retrieve the token
$post_data = array(
    "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
    "client_id" => $client_id,
    "client_secret" => $client_secret
);              

$url='https://***.authentication.us10.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/token';

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

$content_type = array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $content_type); 

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I have managed to get this working using POSTMAN with the same Client Id and secret. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Martin